# okhttp3 mocks not working with Groovy's built-in URL

Tags: groovy, okhttp

I'm trying to use okhttp3's `MockWebServer` and `MockResponse` classes in my unit tests.  I would think this test would pass.

```
package org.example
import okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockResponse
import okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class MockTest {
    @Test
    void test_a_mock() {
        def mockWebServer = new MockWebServer()
        def mockResponse = new MockResponse(status: 200, body:"Hello!")
        mockWebServer.enqueue(mockResponse)
        def bodyText = new URL(mockWebServer.url("/").toString()).getText()
        assert bodyText == "Hello!"
    }
}
```

But when I run it, I get `java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response`

I thought I might be mis-using `URL`, but this test passes

```
    @Test
    void test_get_google() {
        def bodyText = new URL("https://www.google.com").text
        assert bodyText.size() > 0
    }
```

Comment: what `println mockWebServer.url('/')` prints?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across the answer:  Don't provide a "status" in the call to `MockResponse()`

Fails:   `def mockResponse = new MockResponse(status:200, body:"Hello!")`

Works:   `def mockResponse = new MockResponse(body:"Hello!")`

Comment: `status` is the whole status-line as string. If you only want to set the code, you can use: `responseCode: 200`